# Can Position Information for a Burned Uniswap V3 NFT Still Be Retrieved?

Tags: uniswap, uniswapv3

Hello StackOverflow community,

I'm currently working with Uniswap V3 NFTs and have a question regarding the retrieval of position information for NFTs that have been burned (i.e., sent to the null address).

As I understand, once a Uniswap V3 NFT is burned, it's permanently removed and its associated liquidity position is also considered to be removed. My question is, is it possible to retrieve the position information of a Uniswap V3 NFT that has been burned? If yes, how can one go about retrieving this historical data from the blockchain? Are there specific events or logs that can be queried to obtain this information?

Any insights or guidance on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Example: This [burned v3 position](https://etherscan.io/nft/0xc36442b4a4522e871399cd717abdd847ab11fe88/360040)
cannot be retrieved, It show `Error: Returned error: execution reverted: Invalid token ID`

[image]